# Best practice for B2C as SAML IDP configuration for multiple service providers

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-app-registration

I followed instruction [Register a SAML application in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and was able to establish sign in for [test app](https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net). However, some questions are still open for me. From the docs:

> If there are properties specified in both the SAML metadata URL and
> the application registration's manifest, they're merged

Does it mean, I can use only `samlMetadataUrl` property from app manifest and not to specify `PartnerEntity` property in policy (and visa versa)?

```
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/Metadata</Item>
      </Metadata>
      .....
```

In microsoft example only manifest file used to specify service provider metadata url. In other examples both were specified. For me worked only if I specify metadata url in both policy and manifest. Possible I had issues with cache during testing (updated settings not propagated immediately) and just single source of metadata url (manifest or policy) is ok.

How should I build infrastructure in order to support multiple saml SP's? I have next ideas:

- Every SP - separate app registration with updated manifest. Same policy (metadata) file for all SP's. No SP specific info in policy file (technical profile with id `PolicyProfile`)
- Separate policy file per saml SP.

With separate policy per SP we can manage output claims per SP. Possible, technically, we can also use just a single app registration (if needed, I don't like it). But number of policy files are limited.

With separate app registration I loose opportunity individually control output claims.

What are the best practicies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In microsoft example only manifest file used to specify service provider metadata url. In other examples both were specified. For me worked only if I specify metadata url in both policy and manifest. Possible I had issues with cache during testing (updated settings not propagated immediately) and just single source of metadata url (manifest or policy) is ok.

This is likely just a propagation issue, it can take a while for the manifest changes to propagate, and for changes to the linked SAML metadata to propagate. I've had issues in the past on test systems where I've been updating the metadata URL/the metadata content and it's taken a while to get the correct result.

> How should I build infrastructure in order to support multiple saml SP's? I have next ideas:
>
> - Every SP - separate app registration with updated manifest. Same policy (metadata) file for all SP's. No SP specific info in policy file (technical profile with id PolicyProfile)
> - Separate policy file per saml SP.

Whatever else you do, have a separate app registration per app. Each app should have its own app registration so you can do things like assign keys properly, link to app metadata, control permissions, and even just control whether an app is registered to use B2C.

You *might* want to do a different policy file per SAML SP if you want to control the attributes returned in the response, or if you want to control session handling differently for different apps. Unless you have a specific reason to create different policy files though, I'd say start with all SPs using the same file.

Historically, you had to set up different policy files for each SP as all the metadata info and SAML configuration went in the policy file. It's still possible to configure it there for backwards compatibility, but having written a few SAML integrations I'd recommend standardising to one policy file is possible and control metadata, etc, in each SP's app registration.